# How and which graphing library to install on Python 3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, graph, charts, homebrew

I have Python 3 on OSX Yosemite installed with Brew. I want to make some simple charts (like in Excel). I run Python from bash. Which library should I investigate, *and* the proper way to have it installed? I am looking for library which is easy to install, and then easy to use. Output probably png files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) is a good choice.
How to install it on OS-X is mentioned in the [installation FAQ](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html).
Especially in combination with [IPython](https://ipython.org/) notebooks it gives you a nice interactive environment to play with it.

Another alternative would be [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). Pre-built packages are [available](http://ricardo.ecn.wfu.edu/pub/gnuplot/).
It is not tied to Python, it is basically a domain specific language for graphing. There are [python bindings](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) available, gut it is also not difficult to use it with `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use commercial libraries, you may also consider [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com).